# maxsplit functionality for regex split

Tags: python, regex, string, split

I have a string like this

```
aa = 'nilesh-sharma-is-learning-python'
```

Now I want to split this string for `-` delimiter and with `max_split` 3 times.
It can be easily do like this

```
In [35]: aa.split('-',3)
Out[35]: ['nilesh', 'sharma', 'is', 'learning-python']
```

Using regex also we can split the string

```
In [36]: re.split('-',aa)
Out[36]: ['nilesh', 'sharma', 'is', 'learning', 'python']
```

How can I implement `max_split` functionality in case of regex split ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [Docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html), you can provide a `maxsplit` argument also. (3rd argument, or keyword `maxsplit`.

```
>>> import re
>>> aa = 'nilesh-sharma-is-learning-python'
>>> re.split('-', aa, maxsplit=3)
['nilesh', 'sharma', 'is', 'learning-python']
>>>
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.split